# What does the f property stand for in google charts

Tags: google-visualization

I am trying to start using google charts but i dont understand what the f property is used for.  It looks like a label in most cases but im not sure.  Here was one of the only mentions of it in the api documentation: "optional f property containing the literal string to be displayed as the label."

Anyone around here use google charts: https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are referring to the DataTable cells' "f" property, it is the formatted value of the cell.  This is the text that will be displayed in place of the raw value of the cell.  As an example, if you had a cell with the value `3` that you wanted to be displayed as `$3.00`, you could enter `{v: 3, f: '$3.00'}` in the cell.